# Has the phrase 'Star Trek' ever been used in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

In all the *Star Trek* series, the basis of the plot generally is trekking around stars.  So, my question is **has the phrase 'Star Trek' ever been used *in* any canon *Star Trek* works?**

Comment: I grepped through the scripts on chakoteya.net and these seem to be the only occurrences of "trek".

Answer (score 95):

## Yes

Notably, in *Star Trek: First Contact* by the man who made the adventures of *Star Trek* possible: **Zefram Cochrane**:

Just to recap, that line goes:

> COCHRANE: And you people, you're all astronauts, ... on some kind of star trek?

Comment: apologies for the poor quality of the video, but it captures the scene I wanted perfectly

Comment: So what did they reply?  *"Yes.  This is what we call a 'first contact' mission."*  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I wish - they just avoided the question

Comment: http://sevspace.com/stupidarchive/sevtrek193.asp.htm

Comment: "Roll Credits" *ding*

Comment: And there's actually a TV Trope about this but I won't mention its name.

Answer (score 80):

In the last episode of The Next Generation, ‘All Good Things...’, [Q *nearly* says it to Picard](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/277.htm):

> It's time to put an end to your trek through the stars

Somewhat disappointingly, he does not simultaneously turn to the camera and wink.

Comment: Great find - I'd forgotten about that!  Because you're answer is just as valid as mine in my opinion (which is all that counts as I asked the question), I'm not going to accept an answer because it would do injustice to the other answer!

Comment: @N_Soong: aw cheers. However, I would say that yours is the actual answer to the question as posed. I think mine’s interesting, but it’s not a literal instance. I wonder if there was anything similar in the Original Series.

Comment: I agree that N_Soong's answer should be accepted.

Comment: @N_Soong Perhaps a community wiki answer with both references would be a way to have one answer that can be accepted?